# What can I do with tin lumps?

Tags: junk-jack-x

I Found some tin lumps while mining and I don't know what to do with them. I tried putting them in the furnace to make a bar but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make Bronze Alloy, which is handy.

First, get Copper and the Tin Lumps and take them to your Anvil. Combine them in your anvil to create Bronze Alloy. Then smelt the Bronze Alloy to get Bronze Bars. You can craft the bars into Nails, Bronze Block, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Anvil + Tin lump + Copper lump = Bronze alloy

Comment: What can I do with these then?

Comment: @Sashley smelt the alloy into a bar. one bar = 2 nails